# Pass function through specific columns with lapply or for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse, lapply

I have created a function that reorganizes a data frame into a list. I want to pass the function through all of the columns in the data frame (excluding the first 2 columns) however, the `lapply` function is returning strange results.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
names <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
titles <- c("P", "S", "S", "P")
day1 <- c(1,0,1,0)
day2 <- c(0,0,1,1)
day3 <- c(1,1,0,0)

df <- data.frame(names, titles, day1, day2, day3)

ids <-df[,1:2]
obs <- df[,3:5]
```

I create the function which searches each "day column" for a 1 or a 0 and reports the "name" and "title" of a row with a 0 (it also removes duplicated values).

```
group_maker1 <- function(x){
  g1 <- ids$names[obs[,x]> 0]
  g2 <- ids$titles[obs[,x]> 0]
  temp <- c(g1,g2)
  temp <- temp[!duplicated(temp)]
  paste(temp)
}

#test group_maker
> group_maker1(3)
[1] "A" "B" "P" "S"
```

In the actual data frame, there are many (>300) columns of "days". I want to pass this `group_maker` function through each column of "days" to the nth day.

I've tried running it through a for loop but the output doesn't seem to store anywhere

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {       # for-loop over columns
  group_maker1 <- function(x){
    g1 <- ids$names[obs[,x]> 0]
    g2 <- ids$titles[obs[,x]> 0]
    temp <- c(g1,g2)
    temp <- temp[!duplicated(temp)]
    paste(temp)
  }
}
```

Alternatively, I tried `lapply`, which seems more promising as it gives an output, however "NA"'s are present, and its not reporting any of the "B" names

```
lapply(obs[,1:3], group_maker1)
$day1
[1] "A"  "C"  "NA" "P"  "S" 

$day2
[1] "A"  "C"  "NA" "P"  "S" 

$day3
[1] "A"  "C"  "NA" "P"  "S"
```

This is the desired output, however the values within it are incorrect. I want it to return the output as seen above in the `group_maker1(3)` line but with the correct values for each column of days (i.e. no "NA's" and all of the values in that column)

Essentially, I want the loop/apply to pass the function through each column of "days" and provide an output of all the "names" and "titles" for each day in the form of a list.

Comment: Your `for` loop simply overwrites the function definition `nrow(df)` times and never calls it, let alone stores the results.  Rather than describing your desired output, please provide it explicitly, ideally as the output from `dput()` or similar.  I am *sure* there are easier ways to do what you want than the approaches you have taken so far.

Comment: I edited the post to clarify. The desired output is presented after inputting the `lapply` function however, as you can see it is not reporting the values correctly (it has NA's that aren't in the columns, and name "B" is missing.). If you run the function column-by-column it works correctly, but this changes when passing it through `lapply`

Comment: I've already pointed you to the typo in your `for` loop.  The problem with your `lapply` is that you pass the *values in the nth column of `obs`* to a function which expects the *index of the nth column of `obs` (that is, simply `n`)* as its input.  Try `lapply(1:3, group_maker1)` instead.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what the problem was. Using `lapply(1:ncol(obs), group_maker)` worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using your test data, we have

```
> group_maker1(1)
[1] "A" "C" "P" "S"
> group_maker1(2)
[1] "C" "D" "S" "P"
> group_maker1(3)
[1] "A" "B" "P" "S"
```

So, we can replicate using a `for` loop with

```
> for(i in 1:3) print(group_maker1(i))
[1] "A" "C" "P" "S"
[1] "C" "D" "S" "P"
[1] "A" "B" "P" "S"
```

or using `lapply` with

```
> lapply(1:3, group_maker1)
[[1]]
[1] "A" "C" "P" "S"

[[2]]
[1] "C" "D" "S" "P"

[[3]]
[1] "A" "B" "P" "S"
```

In both cases, your attempt failed because of a simple typo.

Or, taking a completely different approach to avoid the explicit use of loops altogether

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    starts_with("day"),
    names_to="col",
    values_to="val"
  ) %>% 
  group_by(col) %>% 
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
      z <- .x %>% filter(val > 0) 
      c(z %>% pull(names) %>% unique(), z %>% pull(titles) %>% unique())
    }
  )
[[1]]
[1] "A" "C" "P" "S"

[[2]]
[1] "C" "D" "S" "P"

[[3]]
[1] "A" "B" "P" "S"
```

This final option could be shorter if there were no need to deal with awkward input and output formats.